# Mulitlpe dropdowns with hidden textfields

Tags: jquery, multiple-instances, each

I'm trying to have a text field show when I select "other" from a drop down. It works fine, but only on the first instance. I need it to work on multiple occasions per page.
I have tried .each(), .foreach() but can't seem to find the right place for it.
how do I get it to function on multiple dropdowns

JS:

```
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('#myselect').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == 2)
            $('#txtData').show();
        else
            $('#txtData').hide();
    });
    }

)
```

HTML:

```
<select id="myselect">



    <option value="" selected="selected">-Select One-</option>

    <option value="No">No</option>
     <option value="2">Yes</option>

</select>
<br />
<input type="text" id="txtData" placeholder="Please Specify..." class="other" style="display:none;"  />
```

Comment: Do all the instances have the same ID? IDs have to be unique.

Comment: Use a class so you can hide and show them all with one operation.

Comment: ids should be unique throughout the entire page, jQuery assumes that to be the case so it will only return one result, the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but see if that
helps you:

[**jsfiddle Demo change()**](http://jsfiddle.net/sjc54/)

I actually switched your code to use `class` and not `ID's` and created several input text for each selectbox.

Otherwise try being more specific please.

**Code**:

```
$('.other').hide();

$('.sectos').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 3){
       $(this).next('input').fadeIn(); 
    }
    else{
       $(this).next('input').fadeOut();        
    }
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. Thank you so much

Comment: Ok, have fun and don't hesitate to ask if you don't understand what did.

Answer (score -1):

this is my first answer!

One way to do this would be to have a separate function for each "group" of inputs, but I assume you don't want to do this so...

I wrapped two of these select/input pairings into fieldsets as follows:

```
<fieldset>
    <select id="myselect">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-Select One-</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="2">Yes</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="txtData" placeholder="Please Specify..." class="other" style="display:none;"  />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <select id="myselect2">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-Select One-</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="2">Yes</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="txtData2" placeholder="Please Specify..." class="other" style="display:none;"  />
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("fieldset").each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){
            if($(this).children("select").val() == 2){
                $(this).children("input").show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).children("input").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This way you now have a parent element for each group of inputs.  You could achieve a similar effect with a div or anything else you want to use.

hope this helps!

Comment: you can just use `.next('input')`

Comment: What if there were additional unrelated inputs between these groupings?  I agree he was a bit unclear with context.

Comment: IF is a big word according to what he describes he is just trying to give the user the input option to describe "other", when building he should address the next() to the relevant input he can even use .next('#id or .class') for more reliability.

Comment: I agree. He should give his inputs a specific class relevant to the selects.